# Once user sign in they are directed to a gravity form - only when it is complete will they be directed to the site

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a survey that needs to be filled out before the user can continue onto the site.

User will be logged in - this is place
Fill out form - this is in place
Redirect to another page - this is in place

I am just not sure of the functionality always directing them to the survey if they did not do it. I have first login which is in place but this doesnt always mean they will complete the form and therefore this does not really work.

Scenarios

if user signs in and has not completed the form, it will be directed to a form page

ELSE

if user signs in and has completed the form, it will be directed to a different page

Any ideas on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Since user needs to be logged in to fill the form, you can keep the status of the form for that user in user meta field.

You can check if user meta exists and if does redirect to home page or if not show the form to fill.

```
if ( ! get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_survey_done', true ) ) {
    // redirect to survey page or where ever you need him/her to go to fill the form
}
```

After they submit the form you should add the user meta so that next time they login you will not redirect them to the survey form.

```
add_user_meta( $user->ID, '_survey_done', 1 );
```